# How to design a custom chat control in android?

Tags: android

I have to design a custom chat control, i planned to use 3 basic view  (listview , edittext and button) to make a custom chat control. 
Do i have to extend view class and override ondraw method to create chat control..

i.e

```
class Mychatcontrol extends view 
{
  override
      ondraw()
    {
        //create listview
        //create edittext
       //create button
    }
}
```

is it possible ? or are they any better way ?
please share any good ideas for creating chat control, with pseudocode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Check this](http://www.eclaxy.com/COCO_IM_Application_for_Android.htm)

This may help you.

Comment: Thanks, but as of now i am only concerned about the UI design. any sample examples, or code snippets will help my to get started.

Comment: Please try this once:  http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/